# update terminal title from standard output of long running command?

Tags: shell-script, tee, named-pipe

I'd like to change the title of a terminal window during a long running command (for example: `git svn fetch`) with values greped from the output, whilst still writing to standard output.

Is this possible using named pipes or tee and xargs?

I'm thinking something like

```
git svn fetch | sed "s/^\(r\d*\).*$/ \"\\\033]0;\"\1\"\\\007\"/" | xargs -l1 echo -ne
```

based on: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html

---

**Update**:

getting this to work would be enough:

```
(echo "r9" ; echo "r10") | sed "s/^\(r\d*\).*$/ \"\\\033]0;\"\1\"\\\007\"/" | xargs -l1 echo -ne
```

**Update 2:**

This almost does what I want. I see r10, but not r9:

```
(echo "r9" ; sleep 1 ; echo "r10") | sed "s/^\(r[0-9]*\)\.*$/\\\033]0;\1\\\007/" | xargs -0 echo -ne
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, but one approach would be to use `tee` to send the output from git to another script AND standard output. Something like:

```
$ git svn fetch | tee grepping-and-prompt-changing-script.sh
```

There are some examples here:

http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/